# How can I find a previous sibling's child?

Tags: jquery, dom

Given this structure:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

...And a reference to `d`, how would I use `jQuery` to select the element with class `b`?

Comment: Can you clarify what does it mean "go to from d to b", what kind of method you're expecting and what is it that you're doing that doesn't work or that you can't figure out?

Comment: What exactly you mean? Are you trying to move d to b?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a method to move all of the content inside div d up into div b? Does d still exist, but after the content move, is empty? Should the content that is being moved be appended onto the existing content in b, or prepended?

Comment: Sorry I was not more specific but all the answers I have been receiving so far answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
$('.d').siblings('.a').find('.b')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d_object.parent().siblings('div.a').children('div.b')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you gave them class names just to reference them in your question.

```
$('.d').siblings(':first').children()
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPZNU/).

Otherwise you could use...

```
$('.d').siblings('.a').children('.b')
```

Comment: Ew. use `.siblings().first()` pseudo selectors are sllooowww.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.d').siblings('div.a:first').find('.b')
```